# Wrap placemark tags with folder tags in KML file

Tags: xml, awk, kml

I have a kml file with hundreds of placemarks and I need to move every placemark into it's own folder.
In this process I need to be able to name/rename every folder by it's placemark name.
Can this be done by using awk, perl or sed? I am not an XML expert.

kml is in the following form:

```
<Folder>
    <name>TEST</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Placemark>
        <name>LOCATION ONE</name>
        [...]
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>LOCATION TWO</name>
        [...]
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>LOCATION ONE &amp; TWO</name>
        [...]
    </Placemark>
</Folder>
```

and it needs to be something like this:

```
<Folder>
        <name>TEST</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Folder>
        <name>LOCATION ONE</name>
        <Placemark>
                <name>LOCATION ONE</name>
                [...]
        </Placemark>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
        <name>LOCATION TWO</name>
        <Placemark>
                <name>LOCATION TWO</name>
                [...]
        </Placemark>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
        <name>LOCATION ONE &amp; TWO</name>
        <Placemark>
                <name>LOCATION ONE &amp; TWO</name>
                [...]
        </Placemark>
        </Folder>
</Folder>
```

So far I managed to wrap every `<placemark>` tag by `<folder>` tag using the following awk commands, but I need to be able to rename every folder by its placemark name too:

```
awk '/<Placemark>/{system("cat file1");next}1' file.kml
awk '/<\/Placemark>/{system("cat file2");next}1' file.kml
```

file1:

```
<Folder>
<name>@@FOLDER@@</name>
<Placemark>
```

file2

```
</Placemark>
</Folder>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should get you going:

```awk
# Expects the file in reverse 
# tac file.xml | awk -f parse_kml.awk | tac

/<\/Placemark>/ {   
    p_flag = 1          # Set flag if inside tag
    print "</Folder>"   # Print closing folder tag
    print $0            # Print current line
    next                # Skip to next line
}
/<Placemark>/ {
    print $0            # Print current line
    print line          # Print name tag
    print "<Folder>"    # Print folder tag
    next                # Skip to next line
}
p_flag && /<name>/ {
    line=$0             # Store the line
}
{
    print $0
}
```

Save to a file such as `parse_kml.awk` and run line:

```
tac file.xml | awk -f parse_kml.awk | tac
```

If you have `xmllint` you can use this format the output:

```
$ tac file.xml | awk -f parse_kml.awk | tac | xmllint --format - 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Folder>
  <name>TEST</name>
  <open>1</open>
  <Folder>
    <name>LOCATION ONE</name>
    <Placemark><name>LOCATION ONE</name>
        [...]
    </Placemark>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
    <name>LOCATION TWO</name>
    <Placemark><name>LOCATION TWO</name>
        [...]
    </Placemark>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
    <name>LOCATION ONE &amp; TWO</name>
    <Placemark><name>LOCATION ONE &amp; TWO</name>
        [...]
    </Placemark>
  </Folder>
</Folder>
```

Comment: This is great! Everything worked, nothing else left for to do. `tac file.xml | awk -f parse_kml.awk | tac | xmllint --format - > file.kml`